# can't use some column methods in migration method change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, database-migration

My Db is changing structure and I have issues using columns methods in my `change` method

here are my models :

```
  Project(id: integer, 
          created_at: datetime, 
          updated_at: datetime, 
          creator_id: integer, 
          brand_id: integer,
          order_id: integer,
          real: boolean, 
          state: string, 
          finished_work_url: string)

  Order(id: integer, 
    created_at: datetime, 
    updated_at: datetime,
    brief_id: integer, 
    state: string, 
    delivered_at: datetime)

  LegalOption(id: integer, 
              project_id: integer, 
              custom_document_file_name: string, 
              custom_document_content_type: string, 
              custom_document_file_size: integer, 
              custom_document_updated_at: datetime)

  Proposal(id: integer, 
    created_at: datetime, 
    updated_at: datetime,
    brief_id: integer, 
    creator_id: integer, 
    description: text, 
    price: float, 
    deposit_percentage: integer)
```

I am changing the column `project_id` with `proposal_id` which is another model. So I want to retrieve my `project_id` for each `LegalOption` and put the right `proposal_id`.  
I tried to use my association between order and project, but I had the error `The method .order() must contain arguments` because of rails conventions.  
Now as my 2 models are created at the same time exactly I want to use the method `created_at` to get the order corresponding to my project. But I have the error :

```
  undefined method `created_at' for #<Project:...
```

and I don't understand why I can't use this method.   
here is my migration code :

```
  class ChangeDbStructureLegal < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def change
      old_db_structure_hash = {}
      LegalOption.all.each do |legal_option|
        old_db_structure_hash[:project_id] = legal_option.project_id
        project = Project.where(id: old_db_structure_hash[:project_id])
        Order.all.each do |o|
          if o.created_at == project.created_at
            proposal = Proposal.where(brief_id: o.brief.id, creator_id: project.creator.id)
            old_db_structure_hash[:proposal_id] = proposal.id
          end
        end

        rename_column :legal_options, :project_id, :proposal_id
        legal_option.proposal_id = old_db_structure_hash[:proposal_id]
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `where` which will always return an association, rather than a single object, so you either need to add `.first` or use find_by instead.

Keeping it as where, you're trying to call .project_id on a list, not an object, which won't work

```
class ChangeDbStructureLegal < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def change
      old_db_structure_hash = {}
      LegalOption.all.each do |legal_option|
        old_db_structure_hash[:project_id] = legal_option.project_id
        project = Project.find_by(id: old_db_structure_hash[:project_id])
        Order.all.each do |o|
          if o.created_at == project.created_at
            proposal = Proposal.find_by(brief_id: o.brief.id, creator_id: project.creator.id)
            old_db_structure_hash[:proposal_id] = proposal.id
          end
        end

        rename_column :legal_options, :project_id, :proposal_id
        legal_option.proposal_id = old_db_structure_hash[:proposal_id]
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I don't know why I haven't thought of that. But now this produces the error :```PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"```

Comment: I will upvote when I get a better reputation, I'm new here ^^